# R programmin help, trying to create a decision tree(now fixed typo)

Tags: r, decision-tree

This is the R command I used to create a decision tree,

```
k <- C5.0(data1[1:16000,-32],as.factor(data2{1:16000,32])
```

but this output I get for error:

> Error: unexpected '{' in "k <- C5.0(data1[1:16000,-32],as.factor(data2{"

Did I forget a bracket? I couldn't figure out why

Comment: You have a `{` instead of a `[` at the end.

Comment: @sumedh Thank you! but now I just got a plus sign keep stucking there forever

Comment: You had one missing `)`. `k <- C5.0(data1[1:16000,-32],as.factor(data2{1:16000,32]))`

Comment: @warner hey now I just a plus sign there keep running forever? what did I do wrong?

Comment: @Sumedh hey sir now I have this error, well not error,  k <- C5.0(data1[1:16000,-32],as.factor(data2[1:16000,32])
+

Comment: @sumedh this plus just keep appearing

Comment: Add a `)` at the end to wrap up the `C5.0()` function. Sorry I didn't catch that the first time. It keeps showing `+` because its expecting another argument.

Comment: @warner hey sorry can you please write an answer? I promise I will accept it! just getting started in R. Here is what on my concolse right now:k <- C5.0(data1[1:16000,-32],as.factor(data2[1:16000,32])
+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
k <- C5.0(data1[1:16000,-32],as.factor(data2[1:16000,32]))
```

You used `{` instead of `[` at the end and you also forgot to include another `)` to wrap up your `C5.0` function.